# C++ - inherting std::tuple from something adding virtual functions to it

Tags: c++, c++11

First is it possible to inherit a std::tuple from something?

I have a

```
std::tuple<A, B> // (common base event data)

std::tuple<C, D, E> someObj;
```

So if I construct the second tuple, the first base class (or something like that) should also be involved.

Secondly, and I suppose more importantly, at runtime I want to choose the correct virtual function based on my type.

So for example if

```
std::tuple<A,B> { virtual void Serialize(); }
```

I'd like to be able to special the child class's Specialize method but using templates so it can be expanded at compile-time but I can choose the method at runtime.

I'm thinking of different to structure the problem in code so that I can achieve this, but if not I'll have to resort to hand-written boilerplate code for each tuple.

Comment: No, a `std::tuple` cannot inherit from some other class, or some other tuple. And your second example makes no sense at at all. Tuples don't have virtual methods.

Comment: You're probably better off just writing classes to store your data. Why do you want to use `std::tuple`?

Comment: Your example isn't C++ code.  None of your code blocks are valid C++ code.  I get it, you didn't mean it to be C++ code, but the rest of your post isn't coherant enough to figure out what you are talking about either.  "something like that", "I suppose", "based on my type", "correct", "special the child", "different to structure" -- lots of nonsense or vague hand waving.  Please actually include as much real code as you can.  Explain what went wrong.  Explain what you are trying to do, tied as much as possible to the concrete code as you can.  Explain why you are doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuple won't magically extends other tuple you want to. You may instead provide your own logic:

```
template<typename... Types>
using child_tuple = std::tuple<A, B, Types...>

template<typename... Args>
auto make_child_tuple(A a, B b, Args&&... args) {
    return child_tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>{a, b, std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

if you want virtual function on tuple (ugh, don't) you will have to introduce your own structs:

```
struct Interface {
    virtual void serialize() = 0;
};

template<typename... Types>
struct poly_child_tuple: Interface, child_tuple<Types...> {
    void serialize () override { /* ... */ }
};
```

However, I strongly recommend that you provide a generic serialize function for your tuples in the form of a template function (please do):

```
template<typename... Types, std::size_t... S>
void serialize(std::index_sequence<S...>, const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple) {
    int unpack[] = {(static_cast<void>(
        [](auto&& value){
            // Do things for each `value` in `tuple`
        }(std::get<S>(tuple))
    ), 0)..., 0};
}

template<typename... Types>
void serialize(const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple) {
    serialize(std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{}, tuple);
}
```

Then, with that implementation, you can call either directly call it for a tuple of known types, or you can call it from a virtual method, which is what you described in your question.

Here's an example of usage:

```
template<typename... Types>
struct serializable_tuple_impl : Interface {
    void serialize() override {
        ::serialize(tuple);
    }

private:
    child_tuple<Types...> tuple;
};
```